# How to fix background-image using Psedo selectors (before)?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, background-image

I want to set background-image to a particular container using Pseudo selector (before) . How can I perfectly set background-image to that particular container?

I want to set background-image to any particular container that i want using pseudo selectors

Comment: paste your code here

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. The `::before` pseudo-element lets you style a pseudo-element … which can't contain anything so isn't a container.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take a moment to review [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and specifically how to create a [minimally, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help you without some code. :-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Quentin , Using ::before pseudo selector, we can set the background-image of a div(container). There is other methods also for setting background-image , but I am using this because I want to change the opacity of background-image and div(container) differently.  Solution of this problem is given by SaurabhLP is below

Comment: @SurajVerma — "Using ::before pseudo selector, we can set the background-image of a div" — No, you can't. You could set the background image of the before pseudo-element and then position it in such a way that it has the same dimensions as the div to which it belongs, but that's not the same as setting the background of the div.

Comment: @Quentin , Thanks. I thought , its both the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have 2 divs as parent and child. You can add a `before` pseudo-element on the parent div.

```css
.first { text-align:center; position: relative; background-image: url(https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/abstract-grunge-decorative-relief-navy-blue-stucco-wall-texture-wide-angle-rough-colored-background_1258-28311.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center; }
.first:before { position:absolute; top:15px; bottom:15px; left:15px; right:15px; content:''; background-image: url(https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/young-asian-man-with-camera-isolated-white-background-photographer-concept_231208-3767.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; background-position: center; }
.second { height:300px; position:relative; }
```

```html
<div class="first"><div class="second">Top<br>Caption</div></div>
```

Thanks